# Android: What is the difference between the two sqlite approaches

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I look at a tutorial here: http://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial-android/android-beginner-tutorial-part-66-creating-sqlite-databases-340

and then I see this tutorial here: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

The first one does not create a class for the table while the second one does. What are the advantages of creating and using that table class and CRUD class?

I need to create an app that will use a fixed structure local database. 3 tables interconnected and mainly display cursors in listviews. I will load cursors into ListViews directly onClick of other listview items. (Categories, Subcategories, FinalItems)

Later I will implement an activity for updating the contents of the database from a remote MySQL server. But this information is just to help you get the big picture.

So for now I just want to know what road to take? Is it necessary to build classes for my tables and for the CRUD operations? Or is it enough to use the first tutorial?

Thank you

Comment: As an aged RDBMS user, I prefer the `rawQuery + execSQL` way, since it gives me a greater control.

Comment: So the first tutorial (without the extra classes)?

Comment: Yes, better (FOR ME - but it's my personal taste). I can't see the tutorial (it asks for a registration, which I'm not going to do). But I can perfectly understand what are you talking about.

Comment: I'm sorry about the registration part... I forgot about that. I made the registration a while ago and I forgot about it. (It's harmless anyway, costs nothing)

Comment: Do you know of a more complete tutorial somewhere with this approach? I also come from the RDBMS world and I like simple things. Why over-complicate something when it's not necessary? This is the reason I asked the question, because I wanted someone to tell me that it's fine with the simple way. I am a newbie in java/android and I learn best by example/code, plus, tips and tricks help me a lot

Comment: If someone disagrees with you (and me) and has arguments for using the second method, please do elaborate. I do not want to wake up in the middle of the project and discover that I want to do something and it's only possible by using classes.. :(

Comment: You might find Lars Vogel tutorials very interesting. [This one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) compares the two techniques.

Comment: Ok, @Vyger please post your comment as an Answer so I can close this question, since nobody else seems to be interested to share their knowledge of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not "necessary" to create classes for your tables.

The reasons for creating such classes is to manage complexity.  Your application sounds very simple, so such classes are likely unnecessary.

Large projects, become increasingly difficult to organize.  At some point, it makes sense to move all of the code that talks to the database into either a single "Data Access Layer" class, or multiple classes (often one per table, but some tables just don't warrant a class).

My current project has to deal with a database containing just over 250 tables, as well as data coming in from web services.  Finding every line of code that talks to table X would be nearly impossible if I didn't have them all grouped neatly into a single class.

It basically comes down to organization.  The more complexity you are facing, the more organized you have to be.